# How to dummy 10 million child nodes to a parent node in realtime database?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

I want to dummy in the real-time database in this structure:

```
{     
     "0" : {
           "0c1592ca-0fa5-43b9-88d2-c9cd77b30611" : {
              "token" : "0cu9CJPb_DIUfbr-Ay8vh6:-KQXn....",
              "member_id" : "123456789102",
              "update_at" : "2021/06/14 08:08:08"
          },
           "<uid>" : {
              "token" : "167 random characters",
              "member_id" : "12 random numbers",
              "update_at" : "YYYY/mm/DD HH:mm:ss"
          }
      },
      "1" : {
       ....
      },
      "2" : {
       ....
     },
      .....
      "9" : {
       ....
     }
}
```

A record is like this:

```
"36 random characters" : {
              "token" : "167 random characters",
              "member_id" : "12 random numbers",
              "update_at" : "YYYY/mm/DD HH:mm:ss"
}
```

I've tried to import JSON files from the firebase console for a million records per node. But I got a crash from the second node, like the image below. I can't import easily like before.
Is there any other way that I can dummy 10 million child nodes like above, faster and stable?

[image]https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuBoM.png

Comment: Please edit your question to include the exact error message and stack trace you get. I also recommend taking some time to study [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as following the guidance in there maximizes the chance that someone can help you.

Answer (score 1):

The error message says that the JSON is invalid, so you might want to pass it through a JSON validator like https://jsonlint.com/.

Aside from that, I can imagine that you browser, the console, or the server runs into memory problems with this number of nodes in one write (see [limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits)). I recommend using the API to instead read the JSON file locally, and then add it to Firebase in chunks, or use a tool like https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/firebase-import.

Also see https://www.google.com/search?q=firebase+realtime+database+upload+large+JSON

Comment: It weird. I've imported a JSON file to node "1" and it succeeded. And right after that, I've imported the same JSON file to node "9", which failed as an invalid JSON file.